# Cutout on overlap from camera perspective

Tags: animation, materials, shaders

I'm currently working on a 3D model with labels that explain the functions of certain parts. As the end product will be used within a hologram pyramid in the end, the model will be continuously rotating to uphold the illusion of a 3-dimensional model.

However, this rotation yields the problem that some lines do overlap with text during certain frames (seen from the camera perspective - they are not actually overlapping). I've read that that Blender offered a possiblity to render the overlapping parts of the objects automatically invisible? Is this possible and if so, how can I achieve this?

I would appreciate any input and thank you in advance.

For copyright reasons I unfortunately cannot share the entire model - however the following screenshots hopefully describe the problem (the animated object is above and the labels are behind each other in the overlapping situation):
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, could you post a screenshot of the problematic parts ? If you can't because of commercial reasons, maybe try with a simpler file or a schematics with paint

Comment: Sure, I added the screenshots directly to the question